# What is the way to store android app resources on a server?

Tags: android, server, rdbms

I'm interested in creating an android app that needs a lot of video clips.
To make the app weight not too heavy, I thought about storing the videos on a server and whenever the user wants to watch the video the app connects to the server and gets access to the video and the user can watch it (of course all this happens inside the application).
so how can i do it in android?
Thanks in advance to everyone

Comment: Of course you can do. and there are hundreds of tutorials available.

Comment: what i need to search? what to learn? how it's work? in the basic of course...

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if you are conversant with web services, but i think the best way is to create a web service and communicate with your application. You will send a request each time a person wants to view that video and fetch it, it sometimes takes a while to load, basing on the algorithm you use, or even internet connectivity, but it is easier, especially with languages like php.
However,Your videos should be compatible with android.

This [tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/streaming-video-in-android-apps--cms-19888) will help you see how to call videos by url.

I also admire this [Website](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/06/android-streaming-live-camera-video-to-web-page/). It shows you how to perform storage and live streaming on both android and the server.